# Python: Create an arbitrary number of nested lists, nested x times

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a function which, given two inputs *r* and *m*, will create a list of *m* lists containing *m* lists containing *m* lists... and so on, *r* times.

Essentially:

```
function(1, 3)
>>> [[], [], []]
function(2, 3)
>>> [ [[], [], []],  [[], [], []],  [[], [], []] ]
```

I've managed to nest *m* lists within an original list, and the problem seems fairly simple, but I'm not sure how to approach automatically going a layer deeper *r* times.

Any ideas?

Comment: Recursion, perhaps? Please share your attempt as a [mre] and ask a _specific_ question about what's wrong with it. Since you're new, please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], 
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursion:

```
def n_l(a, b):
   return [[] if a == 1 else n_l(a-1, b) for _ in range(b)]

print(n_l(1, 3))
print(n_l(2, 3))
```

Output:

```
[[], [], []]
[[[], [], []], [[], [], []], [[], [], []]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This function should work:

```py
def function(r,m):
    result_list = list()
    for _ in range(r):
       temp_list = list()
       for _ in range(m):
          temp_list.append([])
       result_list.append(temp_list)
    return result_list
```

for example, `function(3,5)` outputs this:

```py
[[[], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], []]]
```

Comment: Unfortunately with this function, the layers of 'nestedness' don't change. So r seems to act as *m* for the first layer, and m acts on the second nested level list, whilst the amount of layers is constant. It would seem recursion was the way to go with this.

Comment: I didn't quite get you.. doesn't the function work properly?